# Remove all the entries of a group if one of them meets a particular criterion

Tags: mysql, sql

I actually want to remove all the rows pertaining to a group (in a group by clause) if one of the entries in that group matches the criterion.
Right now the query I am running actually is a kind of tuple matching, which is super slow.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (column1, column2, column3) not in 
       ((SELECT column1, column2, column3
         FROM Table
         WHERE column4 like 'abcd'))
```

Comment: Do a NOT EXISTS instead. Or, even better, do a LEFT JOIN!

Comment: can you provide a query, it would be very helpful.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of "lines to exclude" of each group, and exclude groups containing them using an `HAVING` clause, like:

```
  SELECT whatever, SUM(criterion_for_a_single_line_to_be_excluded) as number_of_lines_to_exclude
    FROM …
GROUP BY whatever
  HAVING number_of_lines_to_exclude = 0
```